# Increment value every 4 seconds

Tags: javascript, alpine.js

Using HTML and AlpineJS I have the following:

```
<div 
  x-data='{ keys: ['a', 'b', 'c'], index: 0 }' 
  x-init="setTimeout(() => i = i < keys.length - 1 ? i + 1 : 0, 4000)">
</div>
```

I need the index to increment every 4 seconds and back to zero when reaches last one.

My code increments from 0 to 1 but it stops there.

How can I make this work?

Comment: `i = (i < keys.length - 1) ? i + 1 : 0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [**setInterval**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setIntervalhttps://) instead of [**setTimeout**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setTimeout) since **setTimeout** will run 1 time after 4 seconds pass after initialization. **setInterval** will run every 4 seconds and if you need to stop it you can use **clearInterval** once your needed condition is met.

Comment: If this was useful please mark it as the accepted solution.